# KVM api to start virtual machine

Tags: python, kvm

I was wondering if there is a KVM API which allows you to start a KVM virtual machine using a simple command, from a python script.

My Python script performs a series of checks to see whether or not we need to start a specific VM, and I would like to start a VM if I need to.

All I need now is to find the API calls, but I can't find a simple call to start them within the libvirt website. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the create() function from the python API bindings of libvirt:

```
import libvirt

#connect to hypervisor running on localhost
conn = libvirt.open('qemu:///system')

dom0 = conn.lookupByName('my-vm-1')
dom0.create()
```

basically the python API is the C API, called by libvirt.C_API_CALL minus the virConnect part or conn.C_API_CALL minus the virDomain part.

see [the libvirt API create call](http://www.libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainCreate) and [here](http://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2008-July/msg00049.html).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, though probably not the best recommended way is to use the os.system using python to invoke qemu-kvm.
This method will have the disadvantage that you will have to manually manage the VM.

Using libvirt, you will first have to define a domain by calling virt-install.

```
virt-install \
         --connect qemu:///system \
         --virt-type kvm \
         --name MyNewVM \
         --ram 512 \
         --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/MyNewVM.img,size=8 \
         --vnc \
         --cdrom /var/lib/libvirt/images/Fedora-14-x86_64-Live-KDE.iso \
         --network network=default,mac=52:54:00:9c:94:3b \
         --os-variant fedora14
```

I have picked this directly from http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VM_lifecycle

Once you create the domain, you can use `virsh start MyNewVM` to start the VM. Using this method, it is much easier to manage the VM.

Comment: Since I am not using my own machine currently, I have tried to answer from experience... Once I get back will try to give you more detailed insns

Comment: Thank you for your response. The os.system is something I have already considered, and I wouldn't need to use virsh to do it, for example I could just do: "os.system("sudo /usr/local/kvm/bin/qemu disk.img -m 1024")". I was just hoping for a cleaner way to do it from python, a module which simply allows to call KVM and start the virtual machine.

Comment: A minor correction, the method you mentioned does not enable hardware virtualization... if you need to actually use kvm, add --enable-kvm

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using libvirt or calling [qemu-]kvm command are the two alternatives for pythonistas. May be you could find interesting snippets in kvmtools project code: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Kvmtools (see ./kvmtools/kvm/build_command.py and kvm_boot_action in ./kvmtools/kvm/action.py making use of subprocess module instead of os.system)

Answer (score 0):

you can use virsh commands if you need to manage your KVM. 
here is the list of virsh commands;

**list deleted because it was not coming in proper format**

you can use the help from virsh to list all the options, there start option might help you.

if you are using the python script for managing you KVM I would suggest to go through the following script as well. it will provide you a good idea. http://russell.ballestrini.net/series/virt-back/